# Disable command but allow to write in command mode

Tags: neovim, command-line, command

I have `fzf.vim` installed, and therefore I have a `:W` command. I prefer working with buffers, so I save a lot with `:w`. However, accidentally using a capital W invokes `:W` which annoys me.

I tried `cnoremap W <nop>`, but now I can't write `:W` at all, the `W` just isn't showing. This isn't what I want.

How to **disable** the `:W` command?

Comment: You could try to `:delcommand W`, but it has to be done after the command is defined (maybe try `~/.vim/after/plugin/fzf-vim-fix.vim` with contents `if exists(':W') is# 2 | delcommand W | endif`--replace bars with newlines--I'm assuming the full command name is `W`, so if the real command is longer use that);

Comment: doesn't work for `W` nor `:W`

Comment: The full command for `:W` is `:Windows`, does `:delcommand Windows` work?

Comment: It is. But `delcommand` is not a statement for `vimrc` =\ How to make It persist?

Comment: Did you put @D.BenKnoble's suggestion in `~/.vim/after/plugin/fzf-vim-fix.vim`? You can’t just put it in your `vimrc`, because the command is registered **_after_** your `vimrc` is sourced. It needs to go in your `~/.vim/after/plugin` directory. Note that `exists(':W')` needs to be `exists(':Windows')`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `is#`? Why would you need that if `exists()` returns a number?

Comment: Omg, that's over complicated. Why should I create a hook or a plugin to disable other plugin commands. There must be a simplier way.

Comment: @kAldown use a different plugin :) or check the docs/code—good ones have ways to disable things.

Comment: @BLayer https://www.arp242.net/effective-vimscript.html

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Sure. I understand that. But I doubt the intent there is to apply that to cases where there's no chance of coercion occurring (e.g. comparing a numeric return value to a number). Speaking as someone who's written and reviewed 100Ks of LoC my opinion, were someone to ask for it ;)  is that that is sacrificing readability at the altar of unnecessary cautiousness. You are, of course, free to act upon or disregard said opinion as you please. :)

Comment: @BLayer I’m not one for dogma (i regularly omit curly braces on single line ifs ) but i kind of like the ring of `is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official response](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1084) from Junegunn is to put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=* W w
```

This will make `:W` behave like `:w`, while still allowing you to use `:Wi` (or any other shortening of `:Windows`) if you want to.